# Getting error while using "bluez-test-input connect <device address> yes" command to connect to a serial Bluetooth module

Tags: 13.04, usb, bluetooth, dbus, raspberrypi

I am using a USB bluetooth dongle on my machine. On the other end, i am having a serial bluetooth module connected to a Micro-controller. On my machine side, i connected and installed my usb-bluetooth dongle using hciconfig tool. But when i am trying to connect it to the serial bluetooth module i am getting a error.

I took following steps

i)   `bluez-simple-agent hci0 <address of the remote bluetooth module>`
ii)  `bluez-test-device trusted <address> yes`

even when i tested by running

```
bluez-test-device trusted <address>
```

i get "1" which define that device is trusted.

iii)  `bluez-test-input connect <address> yes`, i get a error

```
File "/usr/bin/bluez-test-input", LIne 40 in  <moudle>
      input.Connect()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", lie 70, in __call__return self._proxy_method(*args, **keywords)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", lie 145, in __call__ **keywords)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", lie 651, in __call__blocking message, timeout)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method "Connect" with signature " " on interface "org.bluez.Input" dosen't exist
```

I don't know what i am lacking. I found the similar issue [here](http://blog.gmane.org/gmane.comp.freedesktop.dbus/month=20130801) and [here](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-960526-start-0.html%5C) but didn't get ant solution. I had followed these links to connect a remote serial bluetooth device ([this one](http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Bluetooth) and [this one](http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2013/09/how-to-connect-the-perixx-bluetooth-keyboard-to-the-raspberry-pi/))